# Mt.exe doesn't like absolute paths in the -dll option

Tags: visual-c++, manifest

Is it just me, or does [Mt.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375649.aspx) hate absolute paths in the `-dll` option?

I have a Visual C++ project in Visual Studio 2008 with a reference to an isolated (registration free) COM DLL. I copy the COM DLL into the project's output directory using a Pre-Build Event. In the project's properties, on the Configuration Properties > Manifest Tool > Isolated COM dialog I used the following settings:

```
Type Library File: $(OutDir)\MyCom.tlb
Registrar Script File:
Component File Name: $(OutDir)\MyCom.dll
Replacements File:
```

Visual Studio shows me the generated command line command:

```
mt.exe /nologo
    /tlb:"C:\[ ... snip ... ]\OtherProject\Release\MyCom.tlb"
    /dll:"C:\[ ... snip ... ]\OtherProject\Release\MyCom.dll"
    /outputresource:"..\Release\OtherProject.exe;#1"
```

It builds fine, but I get a runtime FileNotFound exception. The application can't find MyCom.dll! Changing `Component File Name` to the following relative path works fine:

```
Component File Name: ..\$(ConfigurationName)\MyCom.dll
```

Comment: mt.exe shipped with Visual Studio 2010 does not report any errors if -dll is given an absolute path.